# how to installing plugin on octobercms

Tags: content-management-system, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I installed octobercms on uwamp as localhost and I'm on windows but I don't know how to install plugins for octobercms, I can't find something like download and then upload to plugin file or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can install a plugin, first, you can download the plugin and copy it to the `plugins` directory in the root of your project. Another way is by going to the admin control panel, whose address is `http://localhost/backend` by default. Then go to `settings` page and from the left menu select `Updates & Plugins`. Now you can click on `install plugins` button and install whatever plugin you want.

Comment: On the site i can't find download link on the plugin

Comment: @Bynd If the plugin is open source, like this one: https://octobercms.com/plugin/clake-userextended, it can be downloaded from its public repository like github: https://github.com/ShawnClake/UserExtended and if the plugin is paid, you cannot download it. The only way to install it is via the latter way I suggested.

Comment: here are a few plugins I can't download
https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user  
  https://octobercms.com/plugin/anandpatel-seoextension
  https://octobercms.com/plugin/martin-forms
  https://octobercms.com/plugin/benfreke-menumanager

Comment: @Bynd In all of those pages, there is a `public repository` link on the lower left corner of the page, which redirect you to where you can download the source code of the plugin. You can also search their name in the `Updates & Plugins` section of your backend area and install them.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins can be installed in multiple ways:

1. Go to the backend of your October CMS installation (usually at /backend). Go to **Settings > Updates** and search for the plugin. This works for all free plugins. Alternatively you can use Composer. Or (if a public Git repository is available) you can just download the code.
2. Login to Octobercms.com and visit the plugin product page in the marketplace. Here you can buy plugins that are paid and/or attach them to a project. You can then attach that project to your October CMS installation from the backend (usually at /backend). Go to **Settings > Updates** and attach the project by it's ID.

Using projects allows you to batch install all the plugins you want to use and handle syncing between a development and a production server.